# php & android howto prevent man-in-the-middle

Tags: php, android, oauth, token, man-in-the-middle

We works on a mobile app that using some web services as backend for db services and others services. We use a password approach for each user to prevent others to connect to ours services. My question is do we need to implements a token based system for preventing "man in the middle" attack? or using https.... or what is best. And if yes wich kind of lib or framework could help us?
Now we protect our function with

```
if (password_verify($userPass, $hashedPass)) 
{
    return true;
}else
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Use security Technics like encryption and decryption of your user name and password.

Comment: yes! i did that allready but i found how to go for prevent this: JWT